# JOIN in Hibernate + sending result to client application

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, web-applications

I'm new to Web Development, I'm trying to build a Web Application using **Angular**, **Spring Boot** and **Hibernate**.

In my database I have two entities (*Order* and *Product*) that are in a "one-to-many" relation (in the *Product* table there is an attribute '*Order*' with the *id* of the relative *Order*).

I want a table to display the information relative to the ***INNER JOIN*** of the two tables (i.e. a table with rows that include information of products and also that are only in the *Order* table, such as the *date* of the order). How am I supposed to proceed?

1. Creating a `ProductInOrder` Object in the server application and generate a list of them performing a INNER JOIN with Hibernate. Then sending the list to the client application.
2. Sending Product and Order tables to the client application, that has to manage the join by itself.
3. Maybe another method?

I started trying with the first method but I was facing some problems:

```
String hql = "select o.id, o.date, p.id, p.name, p.url from Product p inner join p.order as o";
```

If I execute this query how can I store the result in an Object and be sure that each table attribute refers to the correct class attribute? So I thought that maybe I was simply going in the wrong direction.

Comment: As I understand the same product can be added to several orders and several orders can have the same product. So, your `order - product` relation rather `many-to-many` than `one-to-many`.

Comment: @SternK no, I confirm to you that the relation is one-to-many. Products are unique as they each have a different id. The same product can't be in two different orders.